# Excel VBA change the value of a cell based on the value of another cell row by row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

Consider the screenshot attached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rCwo.png)

I would like to add a button to the worksheet that, when clicked, it would go row by row checking if the first column of the row contains "Italy" or "Spain". If it does, it should set its points (cell next to it) to 0.

I would like to do it with some kind of loop or iteration (not with a bunch of If/Else If), but I'm not an expert on VBA, I'm learning on my own and I honestly don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know how to go to `Insert`, `Shapes`, pick any shape (basic rectangles, circles or anything else) and place it it your sheet, you can right click on the shape and asign macro.

You can paste this macro into VBA macro editor and save, and then run or do as I said to asign it to the shape where you can click at will.

Im sure others could give you a better macro. This is very basic. And looping over values is very inificient & slow , but it does what you asked for.

```
Sub MyFirstMacro()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
     If IsError(myCell.Value) Then
      myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Do you know you had an error in " & myCell.Address & "???"
         Else:
            If myCell.Value = "Italy" Or myCell.Value = "Spain" Then
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = 0
            End If
     End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot. I was stuck with that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ironically I do feel this macro is a) yes, doing it by iteration, but also b) is a bunch of if/else Ifs (essentially) . There's a faster cleaner ways :(evaluate range. Method) and arrays. I'm going to put it on code review somewhere so I can also learn improve. But Thanks for accepting the answer !